# Is it possible to add a username and password when mapping a network printer on Windows 10 in the command line?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, network-printer

For instance,

start \server\printername (username) (password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to provide credentials temporarily – connect to the server via `net use` first:

```
net use \\server * /user:foo@domain.tld
```

Every access to that server (including through UNC paths) will use the connection that was established.

If the credentials should be stored permanently, you can add them using `cmdkey` instead:

```
cmdkey /add:server /user:foo@domain.tld /pass
```